# Automatic weight rigging problem

Tags: rigging

I've been here for 6 hours now trying to find out what's wrong, this hand doesnt rig properly, all other objects I try work, so I have no idea whats wrong. I have redone the rig 6 times, and I'm new to blender so I don't have much knowledge.

[image]

Comment: Is your sceletion in the rest pose, when you assign the automatic weights? (You can see the rest pose in the armature's Edit Mode).

Comment: generally parent with automatic weight doesn't work for complex part of the mesh like hands, you need to give correction in weight paint mode and reassign the vertices to their group

Answer (score 0):

Your bone axis may be misaligned that would throw off rotations and cause other problems.